# Most efficient way to convert json in regex C#

Tags: c#, json, regex

Json:

```
[{"Command":"Notificaion-:hi","ID":"142245","AnotherColumn":"data1"},
{"Command":"Notificaion-:hi2","ID":"14255","AnotherColumn":"data2"},
{"Command":"Notificaion-:hi5","ID":"1421245","AnotherColumn":"data4"},
{"Command":"Notificaion-:hi3","ID":"14221145","AnotherColumn":"data2"}]
```

Im thinking of using a MatchCollection where each match is from {...}. odd group numbers are column names and par column numbers are data.

Im stuck with:

```
{(?:(?:(?:\"(.*?)\":)\"(.*?)\",))+?(?:\"(.*?)\":)\"(.*?)\"}
```

and

```
{(?:(?:(?:\"(.*?)\":)\"(.*?)\",))*?(?:\"(.*?)\":)\"(.*?)\"}
```

None of which are giving desired results.

Comment: Most efficient way to deal with JSON would be to use a JSON parser, not Regex... For instance, you could use `JavascriptSerializer` which is a part of .NET framework. Do you have a reason for wanting Regex specifically?

Comment: Are you sure you want to parse JSON using regex? There are several libraries that would do it for you. (unless of course it's for your own entertainment, but then I don't see why you would ask for help here).

Comment: Im well aware of the many.. many.. many libraries and their efficiency
I'm looking, however, to parse it with regex

Comment: @Zananok why? Is it just for your own entertainment? If so, it'd be better to say which part is tripping you up then asking for a solution since that way you'll learn better.

Comment: I wouldn't call it for my entertainment, its purpose is for something else, but it was best explained using that JSON string. Im getting stuck on the first part of the loop: (?:(?:\"(.*?)\":)\"(.*?)\",))+?

I am not managing to get all columns (and data), it seems to skip either the last or the first column

Comment: Since it's late I'll just give a quick response based on the either first or last part of your comment. My experience with either first or last is that you're using greedy/lazy operators and one goes for too much, the other for too little so you need to give it more info on where to stop, probably add another separator or something... If you haven't found your answer by tommorow when I get back here I'll give it a more in-depth look.

Comment: @Zananok: then *explain your question in those terms*. Don't deride those trying to help you in the comments when they see you doing something terribly inefficient or outright unworkable.

Comment: ... I came here to make a question and hopefully get an answer. I was not deriding anyone, but you right now for lack of logics and seeing that I am the one being derided. I am not going to post my whole code for everyone read through the whole thing to come back to me to this small point which is largely unrelated. I have made my question precise and coherent. If you want to debate on how things should be done without the lack of knowledge about my reasons.. then I am sorry. you are on the wrong commenting section. Please read my message and stop answering illogical or descriptive comments.

Comment: This is about me learning how to recursively get the data I want. Its not about using this as a replacement of regex parses in real world applications, although using it to parse a small JSON string is exactly the perfect example I can use to learn it and to explain my needs.

Comment: To aid your learning, I would suggest that using `.*` or `.*?` is a poor way of getting a good regular expression. You have well formatted data, there are lots of double quotes enclosing items, so use them. To match `,"ID":"1421245",` I would use something like `,"([^"]+)":"([^"]+)",`. Note character class that matches everything except the double quotes. You might go even more restrictive and use `,"(\w+)":"(\d+)",`.

Comment: Although perhaps simple, your recommendation of `"([^"]+)":"([^"]+)",` greatly helped me, I appreciate a lot your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{(?:(?:"([^"]+)":"([^"]+)"(?:\s*,\s*)?))+}
```

or

```
{(?:(?:"(.+?)":"(.+?)"(?:\s*,\s*)?))+}
```

Columns names are captures in group 1. Values are in captures of group 2.